# Storing user based events in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We are building a events data store on top of elasticsearch. Our goal is to provide real-time analytics with advanced segmentation on top of users & events. Our entities are

Users or Visitors
Events (Which is performed by Users, which will be above 100 - 1000)

**Example:**

```
{
"first_name": "John",
"email": "john@es.com",
"country": "US",
"user_id": 100
}

{
"event_name": "Add To Cart",
"user_id": 100,
"product_name": "IPhone X"
}
```

I tried 2 options

**Nested Documents**, a concern is user attributes will not be modified frequently. But, events will be performed very frequently. Let's say a user will perform 1000+ events, so the same doc will be updated more than 1000 times.

**Parent-Child Relationship**, not satisfying segmentation

Possible Queries:

Give me the user ids, who is in the US and performed "Add To Cart" & product name is "iPhone X"
With nested documents, it is working out well. But parent-child, I couldn't able to perform the search on parent & child at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how what is your mapping and how you are creating those documents, but it would look something like this:

```
PUT events

PUT events/_doc/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "relation": {
      "type": "join",
      "relations": {
        "owner": "related_event"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT events/_doc/100
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "email": "john@es.com",
  "country": "US",
  "user_id": 100,
  "relation": {
    "name": "owner"
  }
}

PUT events/_doc/2034?routing=100
{
  "event_name": "Add To Cart",
  "user_id": 100,
  "product_name": "IPhone X",
  "relation": {
    "name": "related_event",
    "parent": 100
  }
}
```

And here is your query:

```
GET events/_search
{
  "_source": "id",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "country": "US"
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "related_event",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "product_name": "IPhone X"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```